# MySQL - selecting products names and id's from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following structure :

```
table 1:     ***catalog_category_product***
**1** category_id   int(10)
**2** product_id    int(10)
**3** position  int(11)
**4** entity_id int(11)
```

```
and table 2: ***catalog_product_entity***
**1**   entity_id int(10) auto
**2**   entity_type_id   smallint(5)
**3**   attribute_set_id smallint(5) 
**4**   type_id          varchar(32)    
**5**   sku_name         varchar(64)    
**6**   has_options      smallint(6)  
**7**   required_options smallint(5)  
**8**   created_at       timestamp        
**9**   updated_at       timestamp
```

I need a query for results by category products and name (sku) for each interrogation. I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT catalog_category_product.category_id, catalog_product_entity.entity_id
FROM catalog_category_product
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity 
ON catalog_category_product.category_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
WHERE catalog_product_entity.entity_id =3
```

Comment: I think line 4th should be `ON catalog_category_product.entity_id  = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
`

Comment: DO you need all products under category name called (sku) ??

Comment: When I am looking in a category I need to see all products in that category.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected results? What's wrong with the query you have

Comment: It is not returning any results. MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )

Comment: Basically I need something like this : Column1 category_id Column 2 Product_id , Column 3 Entity_id, Column 4 SKU

Comment: first of all. why are you using raw query's for magento?
Second, you are matching the catalog ID to the product ID(entity_id)?

That's why  you don't get any matches..

Answer (score 0):

The 4th line should be `ON catalog_category_product.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id` which makes valid JOIN.

Because 1st rule of join is Primary key of table 1 becomes Foreign key of 2nd table.

Comment: I'm not sure, in one table entity id is 10 bits, the other is 11, so the join wouldn't work, right?

Comment: If you know the Magento database you can see the structure. Basically I need something like this : Column1 category_id Column 2 Product_id , Column 3 Entity_id, Column 4 SKU